# Output of unique function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using the `unique` function in Matlab and I am confused about the output of such a function.

Consider the following simple code

```
rng default
T=randn(232,50); %232*50
equalorder=randsample(232,80802,true); %80802*1
T_extended=T(equalorder,:); %80802*50
```

By construction, I expect the size of `T_extended` to be `232`. In fact,

```
S=size(unique(T_extended,'rows'),1); %232
```

Now, consider the specific `T` and `equalorder` function that are produced by some codes of mine (`T` and `equalorder` are upload here

https://filebin.net/603zn7mt2efzq91c

unfortunately my code is too long to be reproduced and I think that the issue may be numerical).  Let's apply the code above to these arrays:

```
clear
load matrices %T, equalorder
T_extended=T(equalorder,:);
```

However, if I do

```
S=size(unique(T_extended,'rows'),1);
```

I get `S=4694` and not `S=232`. Why?

Comment: Thanks @PranavHosangadi: I don't know how to do that, it's very long and I'm unable to reproduce my exact numbers with any shorter example.

Comment: The link should work now. Thanks

Comment: `equalorder` has shape 80802x1. `T` doesn't have 80802 rows. Did you mean to do `T(equalorder)` instead of `T(equalorder, :)`?

Comment: `T` is a matrix `232*50` as indicated above. `equalorder` contains `80802`  integers between `1` and `232`, some of them clearly repeated. By doing `T(equalorder,:)` I expand `T` by repeating the rows of `T` as indicated by the indices in `equalorder`. For example, if `equalorder=[1 1 2 ...]`, then `T_extended=[T(1,:); T(1,:); T(2,;)]`

Comment: Thanks. The issue here is that `unique(T_extended,'rows')` should have `232` rows by construction and it doesn't. Why?

Comment: Oops, didn't notice you did `'rows'` already. This is weird. I don't have access to Matlab at the moment, I'll take a look later when I do.

Comment: I played with it in Octave a little bit and see that `unique(T_extended(:, 1:36), 'rows');` gives 232x36, but `unique(T_extended(:, 1:37), 'rows');` gives 582x37. _Really weird!_ Could the array be exceeding a size limit for `unique` when it has more than 37 columns and 80k+ rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The code or data necessary to reproduce the problem should be included in the question itself, as external links may stop working in the future. In this case, however, it was easy to identify the pattern that causes the problem (see below), so the question together with this answer should be self-contained.*

---

In your linked example, `T` contains `NaN` at entry `(216,37)`:

```
>> T(216,37)
ans =
   NaN
```

(and this is the only such entry):

```
>> nnz(isnan(T))
ans =
     1
```

By design, [`NaN` values are not equal to each other](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html#f91-998324). So when computing `unique(T_extended, 'rows')`, all rows of `T_extended` that correspond to the original `216`-th row of `T` are counted as being *different*. This is what causes the count of unique rows to increase. If you don't consider the `37`-the column (which is the only one that contains `NaN`) you get the expected result:

```
>> S=size(unique(T_extended(:,[1:36 38:end]),'rows'),1)
S =
   232
```

Let's count how many times a `NaN` entry appears in `T_extended`:

```
>> nnz(isnan(T_extended))
ans =
        4465
```

(Of course, this happens because):

```
>> sum(equalorder==216)
ans =
        4465
```

This means that the count of unique rows is increased by `4465 - 1` when each *repetition* of the row containing `NaN` is counted as a different row. And `4465 - 1 + 232` is `4696`, which is the result you get.

Comment: Nice! I agonized over why this was happening for way too long but never thought to look through the values. Good to know that `unique` isn't inexplicably broken!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yeah! Now the question for OP is how they managed to get a `NaN` there... so it probably _is_ a numerical issue, after all